# Появление текста и эффектов при наведении на блок

Tags: css3, html, css

Подскажите, как организовать в css появление текста и эффектов из ниоткуда при наведении мыши на объект, т.е. при hover. Просто я могу сделать плавное выделение объекта и т.д., т.е. изменение его стиля, но как создать на блоке текст или внутренние рамки, кнопки, как эффект?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Внутри блока сделать еще один блок. В стилях `.first_block:hover .second_block { animate`...

```css
.first_block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px red solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.second_block {
  display: none;
}

.first_block:hover .second_block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="first_block">
  <div class="second_block">
    Текст
  </div>
</div>
```